# Qt5 How many compilers needed for Android support

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I'm new to using Qt5 and I'm wondering how many compilers are needed to support the majority of Android devices? Which compilers cover the most devices.

In addition when submitting to Google Play do I have to specify a different build for every single device? Or do they have a method that lets you map APK files to compiler version?

Any advice for the process of going from Qt Creator to having an APK or multiple APKs that support the majority of devices.

Comment: How many compilers? Your question seems odd since it appears you do know the different between compilers and APKs. Or are you confused about Android API support http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html vs. Screen size support http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ?

Comment: I'm wondering how many compilers are needed. I downloaded Qt Creator and the Android SDK/NDK and by default it came with 1 android compiler. I realize I need to download more but which ones do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to download additional API packages.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

It depends on how many different API versions you want to support. As a first cut you can look at the Google Play Dashboard

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

which should give you an idea of the population of devices running which version of Android.

Given that Qt 5.x for Android supports API level 10 (Gingerbread), you should start there.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html

Comment: Isn't compiler different from api version? The compilers seem to include stuff like x86, Arm, and mips.

Comment: The single NDK download holds all of the compilers (x86,ARM,Mips) for all of the C/C++ code from Qt. The SDK handles the Java and Android APIs. You'll need the Java bit as all Android apps have to go through the Java side (that just the way it was designed). But if you have downloaded all of the stuff for Qt on Android - I'm still confused by your question. Have you tried to run a demo app at least?

Comment: Your qt-project.org link is dead